# ros3djs URDF not visible, but mesh loading works?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-kinetic, ros3djs, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Im trying to use ros3djs to setup a web interface and load my URDF. I've seen this problem around on the net but nobody seems to have a fix for it? My urdf just isn't loading however there is no visible errors. Below is how i am currently loading in the urdf:

```
this.rosBridgeServer = new ROSLIB.Ros({
  url: 'ws://localhost:9090'
})
//Create 3D Ros viewer.
this.rosViewer3D = new ROS3D.Viewer({
  divID : this.rosViewer3DContainer.id,
  width : 800,
  height : 600,
  antialias : true,
  intensity : 0.05,
  background : '#303030'
});

// Add a grid.
this.rosViewer3D.addObject(new ROS3D.Grid());

// Setup a client to listen to TFs.
this.rosTFClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
  ros : this.rosBridgeServer,
  angularThres : 0.01,
  transThres : 0.01,
  rate : 10.0
});

// Setup the URDF client.
this.rosUrdfClient = new ROS3D.UrdfClient({
  ros : this.rosBridgeServer,
  tfClient : this.rosTFClient,
  path : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
  rootObject : this.rosViewer3D.scene,
  loader : ROS3D.COLLADA_LOADER,
  param: 'robot_description'
});
```

I am using the following library versions (where ros3djs is the most recent version downloaded for local debugging):

```
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/threejs/r89/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/threejs/current/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/0.4.14/eventemitter2.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/ros3djs/0.18.0/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/0.20.0/roslib.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ros3d.js"></script>
```

All my mesh files are in both .stl and .dae, i know the collada loader is working because i can load a mesh **completely** fine by using the ros3djs `MeshResource`:

```
const mesh = new ROS3D.MeshResource({
    resource: 'warthog_description/meshes/chassis.dae',
    path: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    warnings: true
});

this.rosViewer3D.add(mesh)
```

and in `ros3d.js` in the `Urdf` class if i make the following change to load the meshes instead of the `SceneNode` all the meshes from the urdf file are loaded (but of course not correctly linked to their respective TF's as SceneNode does)

**Line 54670 from `ros3d.js:`**

```
// ignore mesh files which are not in Collada or STL format
if (fileType === '.dae' || fileType === '.stl') {
  // create the model
  var mesh = new MeshResource({
    path : path,
    resource : uri,
    loader : loader,
    material : colorMaterial
  });

  // check for a scale
  if(link.visuals[i].geometry.scale) {
    mesh.scale.copy(visual.geometry.scale);
  }

  // create a scene node with the model
  var sceneNode = new SceneNode({
    frameID : frameID,
    pose : visual.origin,
    tfClient : tfClient,
    object : mesh
  });
  // this.add(sceneNode);
  this.add(mesh); // ADDING THIS LINE LOADS ALL MESHES COMPLETELY FINE??????
} else {
  console.warn('Could not load geometry mesh: '+uri);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321513/ros3djs-urdf-not-visible,-but-mesh-loading-works?/) by [agurman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40767/agurman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2019-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue solved!

For anyone who run's into this issue, my problem was that the `tf2_web_republisher` node wasn't running. This meant the meshes where getting no transform. I added the republisher to a launch file and it worked!

---

Originally posted by [agurman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40767/agurman/) with karma: 111 on 2019-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0